# Warning inesperada al devolver una posición de memoria de una variable local

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

La consigna es la siguiente:

> Hacer una función que redondee al entero más próximo el valor contenido
> en una variable externa de tipo double.

Lo que intenté realizar fue crear una variable local tipo double en la función "devolver_posicion_memoria", y luego devolver la posición de memoria de dicha variable, para así luego poderla modificar en el MAIN. Si bien la consigna no especifica que la variable mencionada deba estar en una función, prefiero hacerlo de esta forma.

Si bien al ejecutar el programa el resultado es correcto (o eso creo), obtengo la siguiente warning:

```
13|warning: initialization of 'int' from 'double *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
```

La línea 13 es la de "int dir_a = &a;"

El código que desarrollé es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int devolver_posicion_memoria(void);

int main()
{
    printf("La posicion de memoria es %d", devolver_posicion_memoria());
}

int devolver_posicion_memoria (void)
{
    double a = 8.644864;
    int dir_a = &a;
    return dir_a;
}
```

Al ejecutar al programa obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` es un tipo de dato que, típicamente, ocupa 4 bytes (en algunas arquitecturas ocupa 2 bytes).

Por otro lado, las direcciones de memoria, en sistemas de 32 bits ocupan 4 bytes... y 8 bytes en 64 bits.

Esto quiere decir que si intentas almacenar una dirección de memoria en un entero es bastante probable que pierdas parte de la dirección, ya que no va a *entrar* en un entero.

Es decir, el compilador se queja, y con razón. Te está avisando que tu código es peligroso por naturaleza y propenso a comportamientos inesperados.

Por otro lado, nota que `a`  es una variable local de la función, es decir, cuando la ejecución abandone la función, la variable se liberará y su espacio de memoria podrá ser utilizado por otras variables. Que tu programa devuelva la dirección de memoria de dicha variable es contraproducente... cuando quieras acceder a esa dirección de memoria podrá contener cualquier valor y cualquier intento por modificarla puede provocar inestabilidad en tu programa.

> y luego devolver la posición de memoria de dicha variable, para así luego poderla modificar en el MAIN

Dado que para devolver la dirección de memoria de una variable basta con usar el `&` no veo necesidad alguna de complicar el código con una función totalmente innecesaria:

```
int main()
{
  double valor = 3.1415;
  double* ptr = &valor;
}
```

Este ejemplo es mucho más seguro y confiable que el que has puesto ... con el aliciente que ocupa menos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Eferion, ya la marqué como correcta.

Te hago una pregunta, cambiaría algo en vez de:
"double* ptr = &valor;"
Colocar:
"double *ptr = &valor;"

Comment: @JuanPabloFrersCampos no, significa exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo por qué es un int en el return type. Debería ser double *.... y si, obviamente el compilador se va a quejar pq no estas manejando conversiones "aceptables", digamos. Para que el compilador no se queje (más no implica que sea correcto) podrías hacer esto:

```
int dir_a = (int) &a;
```

Pero creo que tu función debería ser:

```
double * blab() {
    double a = 8.64;
    return &a;
}
```

De cualquier forma, esa localidad de memoria está *liberada* una vez que sales de la función porque no la creas de forma dinámica sino a partir de una variable local de la función que va a morir tan pronto salgas de ella.

PS: Y puedes usar `%p` en el printf para imprimir una dirección de memoria si lo que tienes es un apuntador.